# Чем отличается -Dmaven.test.skip=true от -Dmaven.test.skip.exec=true?

Tags: apache, maven, сборка, юнит-тесты, build

Чем отличается -Dmaven.test.skip=true от -Dmaven.test.skip.exec=true?

Comment: 2 запускает

Comment: Что запускает? Тесты? Опция же test.skip называется...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**-Dmaven.test.skip.test.exec=true** позволяет пропустить выполнение тестов. При этом тесты будут компилироваться. Эквивалентом является более короткая запись **-DskipTests**.

**-Dmaven.test.skip=true** позволяет пропустить не только выполнение тестов, но и их компиляцию.

Comment: А вы не ошиблись написав -Dmaven.test.skip.test=true вместо -Dmaven.test.skip=true?

Comment: @abg Да, ошибся. Спасибо.